# How can I set the table width to be the width of the subpoint?

Tags: tables, columns, width

I have a table which can get aligned to the column width but the table is a part of the subpoint. By subpoint I mean (an itemize within an itemize or a point within a list of points), the width should be lesser than the column. It's 2 column page. Therefore I need it to be aligned to subpoint width.
Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Time complexity for heap operations}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline\hline 
Implementation & deletemin(d) & insert/decreasekey(i) & {|V| x d + (|V| + |E| x i ) }\\
\hline
Binary heap    & O(log |V|)         & O(log |V|)                  & O((|V| + |E| )log |V|)  \\
d-ary heap     & O(\[\dfrac{dlog|V|}{log d}\])        & O(\[\dfrac{log|V|}{log d}\])                 & O((|V|\dot d + |E| )\[\dfrac{log|V|}{log d}\])              \\
Fibonacci heap & O(log |V|)         & O(1) (amortized)                  &O(|V|log |V| + |E|)  \\
\end{tabular}}
```

Here is the result: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is a `subpoint`? Do  you mean the width of paragraph by the current `\item`?

Comment: Off-topic but you need to replace `log` with `\log`

Comment: PLease make your code compilabe (you have many errors in code) and extend this code sniped to complete small document with   `\documentclass{...}` on its beginning and `\end{document}` on the end. It seems that your table is to wide to be fit into column width (even with use of `\tiny` font size). A solution can be make table over both document columns with use   `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}`.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

If the table is part of the list structure you can sized it to `\linewidth` rather than `\columnwidth` but also you should *just* have the `tabular` and remove the `table` environment. The only purpose of `table` is to specify that the table is a floating environment that may be moved to help with page breaking, so it may not appear within the list, so by design the table environment resets most settings so they are not affected by the environment where you set the table.

I would never apply `\resizebox` to a table it produces font sizes that are inconsistent with the rest of the document.  You can use `tabular*` to force the table width to be `\linewidth` without needing to distort the font size.

Comment: Don't forget \captionof{table} and possibly a minipage.